# How does $f(z) = ic^{(1-z)}$ transform a certain region D on the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

The region is $ D = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}: Re(z) > 1; 0 < Im(z) < \frac{\pi}{2} \}$ and the transform is $f(z) = ic^{(1-z)}$ where $c$ is a constant.

I'm not sure where to begin as I've never come across a transform where $z$ is the power (asides from $exp(z)$) and I while I know that $z+1$ and $z-1$ move the plane a distace $1$ towards the right and the left, I'm not sure how $1-z$ behaves.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you describe what happens when you specialize $c = \mathrm{e}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I don't know how to format 
Is my first post on stack.exchange
Hope it helps

f(z) = ic^(1-z)

- ie^((1-z)ln(c))
- ie^(ln(c) - (x+iy)ln(c))
- ie^(ln(c) - xln(c) -iyln(c))
- ie^(ln(c^(1-x)) -iyln(c))
- ic^(1-x).(cos(yln(c)) - i.sin(yln(c))
- u = c^(1-x).sin(yln(c))
- v = c^(1-x).cos(yln(c))

Other approach can be to take log on both sides

As x approaches infinity
f(z) approaches origin

When u take y = 0
And let x move from 1 to infinity
v goes from 1 to 0 for c>=1